# Unicode controls delphi 2010

Tags: delphi, unicode, delphi-2010

I have a projects with Delphi 5 use TntUnicode,
 And now, i build it in delphi 2010; but i have some problem with Unicode 
 ( delphi 2010 suport      Unicode, so i don't use TntUnicode Control );

First:  How to replace 2 function

```
    WideCanvasTextExtent(TextBitmap.Canvas, Caption) 
    ;WideCanvasTextOut(TextBitmap.Canvas,0,0,Caption);
```

Else:

```
    GetText; SetText; IsCaptionStored ;
```

in Controls units  not be declared ;﻿

Comment: I don't understand why you have not accepted Remy's excellent answer

Answer (score 4):

`WideCanvasTextExtent()` and `WideCanvasTextOut()` are third-party functions, probably part of TnT.  Just use the `Canvas.TextExtent` and `Canvas.TextOut()` methods instead, since they are Unicode now:

```
TextBitmap.Canvas.TextExtent(Caption);
TextBitmap.Canvas.TextOut(0,0,Caption);
```

`GetText()` and `SetText()` are the getter/setter methods for the `TControl.Caption` and `TControl.Text` properties.  You should not be calling the methods directly, use the properties instead.  Some controls publish the `Caption` property, and some controls publish the `Text` property instead.

`IsCaptionStored()` is used by the `TControl.Caption` property for controlling DFM streaming.  Again, not something you should be calling directly.

Comment: So, How can i call GetText() ; SetText() and IsCaptionStored();
Because i have a class
TDynaLED = class(TGraphicControl)
....
// property Caption;
    property Caption: TCaption read GetCaption write SetCaption stored IsCaptionStored;

Comment: Im afriad we won't be able to help you much if you don't show us original code. Both Gettext() and SetText() have probably been modified extensively in order to make unicode work. But now on newer Delphi versions they might even not be needed any more. But in order for us to tell you wheter they are needed or what changes might be necessary to them we need to see their original code. As for IsCaptionStored I asume that might do something with optimization so that Unicode decoding routines aren't called when not needed (no text stored in caption)

Comment: Again, DO NOT call `IsCaptionStored()` yourself. The DFM streaming system calls it for you. As for `Get/SetText()`, again use the `Caption` property instead. `TDynaLED` derives from `TGraphicControl`, so it should be promoting the property from `protected` to either `public` or `published` so it can be accessed.